# Best way to Implement interrelated tuple sin a database, such as Part Exchange cars

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, entity-relationship, database-normalization

Im designing a car dealership management system, and i have the following entities:

Cars, Sale, Purchase, Seller, Buyer, Expense. The relationship between them is straight forward; a car can have many expenses but one sale and one purchase. A sale can have one buyer, and a purchase can have one seller.

The trouble is implementing part exchange vehicles. These are basically vehicles that are related to one another and are in the same table: When a car is sold, it can have either a Cash Price, Card price or a part exchange price assigned to it which is basically the value/money the dealership has received as payment. This means that a car can be paid for using another car in the same table. But i dont want to create a Part Exchange Price field for every car as such occurrences are rare.

What is the best way of establishing such connections within the same table so that i can query stuff like "What are all the cars that were sold on a part exchange basis and what cars did i receive in exchange for them"

Let me know if i need to clarify something :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), relating Cars to itself, call the table something like CarPartExchange with columns:

- SoldCarId - a reference to the Car that was sold,
- ExchangedCarId - a reference to the Car that was exchanged, and
- PartExchangePrice - the price used for the exchange.

> What are all the cars that were sold on a part exchange basis

```
select SoldCarId from CarPartExchange;
```

> and what cars did i receive in exchange for them

```
select SoldCarId, ExchangedCarId from CarPartExchange
inner join Car SoldCar on SoldCar.Id = CarPartExchange.SoldCarId
inner join Car ExchangedCar on ExchangedCar.Id = CarPartExchange.ExchangedCarId
where PartExchangePrice > 100;
```

The joins would be necessary in the above example if you want to include information from the Car table in your results. I'm using an arbitrary example finding all exchanges with a price greater than 100.

Comment: How do i set up the relationships? Or can i just leave them out?

Comment: The relationships are established by records in the CarPartExchange table. See my edit.

Comment: Jinx, i just added that to my table as well. As for the relationships ive made a One to Many that is, one RegistrationNo in the main cars table to many SoldCarId in the junction table. Is this fine?

Comment: Yes if that's your unique identifier for a Car. In that case I'd rename the SoldCarId column as SoldRegistrationNo, and similar for ExchangedCarId.

Comment: One quick questions, whats the point of establishing relationships in Access when i can just use SQLs WHERE statements to link to ids?

Comment: And thankyou so much, perfect answer and example!! :)

Comment: The relationships tell Access which columns you're using for foreign keys so it can optimize queries and help you construct queries faster.